# using pdf files and their metadata for Azure cognitive search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm uploading hundreds of PDF files into blob storage to be used in Azure cognitive search.
I would like the user to be able to get the title and author of these PDF files on top of their search results.
I'm not sure how the metadata for these PDF files (e.g., 'author', 'date', 'title') can be added (e.g., as a json file) to the blob storage.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. Azure blob storage has blob properties and metadata built into it! You can view and add metadata through various tools including the Azure Portal, CLI, PowerShell, or the REST API. To learn more, here's a great area to get started:

- [View Blob Properties and Meta Data using Azure Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/organize-blobs-properties-metadata/3-view-blob-properties-and-metadata-using-azure-tools-and-code)
- [Add Blob Metadata using Azure tools and code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/organize-blobs-properties-metadata/5-add-blob-metadata-using-azure-tools-and-code)

Comment: This ultimately boils down to a **link-only answer**. On Stack Overflow, answers should be self-contained. Answers may include links, but the links should be to provide additional details, not relied upon to answer the question. Please [edit] your answer to include additional details and, ideally, sample code.

Comment: In my answer, I verified that you can edit them and that there are 4 ways to do so. The link boils down the 4 ways to do with concrete examples. Does this not work?

Comment: It's definitely on the fence. Is there a general data model for the metadata that you can provide details on? (E.g., I assume the metadata is stored in a property bag that has a consistent name across the various APIs?) Alternatively, it may be useful to include an example using the Azure CLI version, and then reference the links for alternate approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the title, author and date to be returned in your search results, you can add them to the index. Thus, you can create fields called `author`, `title` and `date` in your **index**. Then, in the **indexer**, you can return the specific metadata for PDF's, as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-blob-metadata-properties), like this:

```
indexer= {
"name":...,
"dataSourceName":...,
"targetIndexName":...,
"skillsetName":...,
"fieldMappings": [
    { 
        ....
        
    },
    {
        "sourceFieldName": "metadata_title",
        "targetFieldName": "title"
    },
    {
        "sourceFieldName": "metadata_creation_date",
        "targetFieldName": "date"
    },
    {
        "sourceFieldName": "metadata_author",
        "targetFieldName": "author"
    }
],
"outputFieldMappings": [
...
]
...
```

}

Where the "..." means that you add your own code.

Of course, the PDF's should have the metadata, otherwise it will return an empty value `[]`.

You can then access the fields like you'd normally do for `content` for example.

NOTE: if you happen to put a null `mappingFunction` for the `title`, `date` and `author`, you might also get a `[]`. If you don't use it, best remove it.